# Dragging audio files out of the browser "natively" onto audio applications?

Tags: audio, drag-and-drop, webkit

Does anybody knows if it is possible to drag a file out of browser ( i'm just concerned about chrome / webkit ) onto an audio application and have the target application handling the file as a "native" drag ?

For instance, drag and audio file into Ableton Live ( or Logic, Pro Tools, etcs ) and have it being opened ?

The behaviour would be analogous to dragging a picture onto Photoshop and having Photoshop handling it.

Comment: Have you looked into native HTML5 drag and drop? GitHub has tons of jQuery/JavaScript projects that do that (well, the drag and drop stuff anyway, not your particular use case).

Comment: Yes i did, and i does work to "drag a file into desktop" for instance. So it will copy the file from the browser into desktop.

But if i try to drag an audio file into an audio software, the audio software doesn't recognise it as "audio" therefore, doesn't "accept" it as it would if i dragged from Finder.

Maybe its a mimetype thing i'm not aware.. But i can't find reference about this anywhere.

Comment: Hmm, interesting...that may just be an implementation of audio software in whole. I just had a thought: maybe the file has to fully downloaded in your web interface to work. On your desktop, the full file is already there. Online, files are merely representations of what's there. Shortcuts really.

Comment: Yeah that is kind of how i felt ( i was dragging shortcuts ) any tip would be more than welcome! thanks

Comment: Maybe you could build a webapp that holds the samples/audio files you want to use in projects. The webapp would use localstorage for the files when clicked on. Maybe have some indicator to show which files have been loaded into localstorage?

Comment: Sorry NetOperator i don't quite understand what you meant, how then i would "Drag out" the files from localStorage ?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. It was more thinking out loud than providing solutions I think could work. You would still be dragging from your web interface and it would still act as a shortcut, but instead of being a shortcut on the web, it would be a shortcut on your system. Not sure if the desired effect would happen at that point though.

Comment: thanks anyway! i'll let you guys know if i come up with a solution